# How to make menu remain visible while on hover

Tags: html, css, submenu

I've created a submenu which appears when you hover over the 'services' link. However, when I move my mouse over to the submenu it disappears due to it sitting below the navigation where I want it to be.

So far I’ve tried leaving the submenu in its natural top position and using z-index to make it sit behind the navigation.  I found that this wouldn't work due to the submenu being positioned absolute.

```css
body {
  font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .25px;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav a {
  color: #000;
}

.nav ul:hover li a {
  color: #eee
}

.nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #333;
}

.nav a:last-child {
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 35px 0 0;
}

.three:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1
}

.sub-menu {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #333;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="one">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="two">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="three">
        <a class="">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-menu"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="four">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The submenu should sit exactly below the navigation and stay visible when I move my mouse across from the link to the submenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included `padding-bottom: 20px;` on hover
the link need to be connected to the submenu so that it is still hovered

```css
body {
  font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .25px;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav a {
  color: #000;
}

.nav ul:hover li a {
  color: #eee
}

.nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav a:last-child {
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 35px 0 0;
}

.three:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1
}

.sub-menu {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #333;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="one">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="two">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="three">
        <a class="">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-menu"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="four">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would the padding still work if I place the sub menu on footer?

Comment: Yes, as long as the link which is to be hovered should be connected to the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin `.nav ul` & add padding for `.nav a`

```
.nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0px;
      margin:0;
    }
.nav a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .25px;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
display: block;
}

.nav ul:hover li a {
  color: #eee
}

.nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #333;
}

.nav a:last-child {
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 35px 0 0;
}

.three:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1
}

.sub-menu {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #333;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="one">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="two">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="three">
        <a class="">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-menu"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="four">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this.

```css
body {
  font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .25px;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav a {
  color: #000;
}

.nav ul:hover li a {
  color: #eee
}

.nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #333;
}

.nav a:last-child {
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 35px 0 0;
}

.three:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1
}

.sub-menu {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #333;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}
.sub-menu::before {
  content: "";
  top: -18px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="one">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="two">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="three">
        <a class="">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-menu"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="four">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this to your existing css, nothing else.

```
.nav a { 
  color: #000; 
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px; 
  margin: 0;
}
```